# Отсутствующий элемент последовательности в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как  определить отсутствующий элемент последовательности чисел в массиве ?

```
$array = [1,2,4,6,7,8,10] == то есть: 3,5,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Берём исходный массив
- Берём массив, где есть **все** числа
- Вычисляем разницу за счёт встроенной функции **[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php)**

---

```
$arrayWithMissingNumbers = [1,2,4,6,7,8,10];
$maxArrayNumber = 10;
$fullArray = range(1, $maxArrayNumber);

$missingNumbers = array_diff($fullArray, $arrayWithMissingNumbers);

---
print_r($missingNumbers);
```

Comment: Спасибо. я думал об этом, но это немного не применимо к моей задаче. мне нужно определять на  основе имеющихся чисел. а не сравнивая с другим массивом. к примеру у меня есть массив $array = [[1], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]]; мне нужно определить размер каждого массива и найти недостающий элемент, якобы это числовая последовательность. я подсчитал  размер каждого массива и получил последовательность 1,3,4. как мне определить что в этой последовательности не хватает цифры 2? или я двигаюсь не в том направление?

Comment: @Igorrr_98 Извините, но вы описали в вопросе конкретную задачу, под которую был дан ответ. Угадать, что оказывается у вас совсем другие услоивия никто не мог. Поэтому я могу лишь рекомендовать закрыть текущий вопрос (с галочкой) и задать новый, где описать как раз всё детально: какую задачу решаете, что есть на входе, что нужно получить на выходе и т.д.